# gui window won't show in netbeans java

Tags: java, swing

Gui windows won't show in java. I have java, netbeans, java jdk. I tested jdk and java with opening .jar file and it works..Here is full code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author swipeales
 */
public class gui extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form gui
     */
    public gui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        labelTittle = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        labelTittle.setText("Title");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(labelTittle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(525, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(labelTittle)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jLabel1.setText("Password: ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(232, 232, 232))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(81, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 286, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // ...


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new gui().setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        );
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelTittle;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have defined is a JPanel. A JPanel is not a top-level component. It can't be made visible on its own, but must be added to a JFrame.

Replace your run method body by

```
gui gui = new gui();
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(gui);
f.pack();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);
```

And please, give a better name than `gui` to your class (something like `PasswordPanel`, for example), and respect the Java naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
public void run() {
    new gui().setVisible(true);
}
```

Put it in a JFrame first, JPanel can't display by itself. For example:

```
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("your window");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new gui());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

By the way, class name should being with uppercase letters. So you may want to name your `gui` class as `Gui` or `GUI`.